# What to do about answer details getting edited out of answer

Tags: support

I asked this question [Can't debug Azure Applications with v1.5 of SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704831/cant-debug-azure-applications-with-v1-5-of-sdk) and the answer was just a link to MSDN. So I edited the answer to include the relevant points from the linked site. My changes were then edited out leaving just an answer with a link again. Should I reedit the answer or post a new answer with the details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the person that approved your edit also "improved" it by removing the substance of your edit. Without asking the person directly we can't know why.

I can't see anything wrong with your edit so I've rolled the answer back to your version.

In general I'd roll back to my edits the once (if I even noticed the change) and then leave it. If the post gets rolled back again you can flag it for moderator attention and they can lock it temporarily (or permanently if required) to prevent edit wars.

Comment: Actually, it looks like an Improved Suggested Edit where only part of the edit was accepted.

Comment: @RobHruska - you're right. I missed that the OP didn't have edit rights.